# convert a date in dd/mm/yyyy to timestamp (seconds since 01/01/1970) in C++

Tags: c++, date, time, timestamp

I'm looking for a way to convert, a formated date dd/mm/yyyy to standard timestamp. using c++ language.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

`strptime` and `mktime`.

Be aware that timezone affects the answer, since a standard timestamp is seconds since 1970 UTC, not necessarily seconds since 1970 local time.

Also be aware that the epoch isn't guaranteed by the C++ standard to be 1970, although it is on common systems.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
struct tm tm;
time_t epoch;
strptime(your_formated_date, "%d/%m/%Y", &tm);
epoch = mktime(&tm);
```